# How to show only weekday on xAxis with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

---

### Summary

**Hi there.**

I'm finding how to show only weekday with Highcharts.

I've done to find how to change xAxis labeling and how to set xAxis formatter, and so on...

but I've not find how to skip weekends yet.

---

### Back ground

I'm on financial data analysis (FX).

FX market is closed on weekends, so I want to hide them on Highcharts graph.

Since I have no idea now, I'm sorry for no reference codes I can show you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uses `xAxis.breaks` [Api documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks) to skip weekends :

```
xAxis: {
  type:'datetime',
  tickInterval: 1,
  breaks: [{
    from: 1246579200000,
    to: 1246838400000,
    breakSize: 3600000 *48, // 2 days gap
    repeat: 604800000 // Repeat every week
  }]
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/rnt50hg9/)

Comment: @puruneko, Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Is it OK? Thanks for your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Highstock, you can also enable `ordinal` option:

```
    xAxis: {
        ordinal: true
    },
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/ordinal-true/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: It's convinience for me! But if plot huge data points, it seems slowing down... In the case, I'll try above answer!

Comment: Hi @puruneko, The `ordinal` option should have better performance than `breaks`. Maybe something else results in lower performance?

Comment: Thanks for replaying @ppotaczek. I code on React.js. I keep trying to find some bottle necks what causes slowing down.

Comment: So, I can recommend you to use the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper for Highcharts: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official